# Unable to get Logging to Work in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, logging, spring-aop

I have a spring MVC application running locally and am trying to implement logging inside an aop aspect class, but when I run it nothing is printed. I have tried both the java util.logger and log4j without success. I don't care which one I use as long as I can get something to work. My ultimate aim is to run the application online and have the logging information print to the tomcat server logs.

My java file is:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

public class ApplicationLoggingAspect {

//setup logger

private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

@Before("forApplication()")
public void before(JoinPoint theJoinPoint) {

    //display name of the method
    String theMethod = theJoinPoint.getSignature().toString();
    logger.info("=======>>in @Before: calling method: " + theMethod)

}
```

}

My log4j properties file is:

```
# LOG4J configuration

status = info
dest = err
name = PropertiesConfig
filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = all
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %m%n
appender.console.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
appender.console.filter.threshold.level = all
rootLogger.level = all
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
log4j2.debug
```

Thanks, Wex

Answer (score 0):

Ahhhhhhhhhhh....

It seems I forgot to put @Aspect and @Component above the class. It works perfectly now.